# Oracle 12c PL/JSON Chopping Off Strings at 5000 Characters

Tags: json, oracle, plsql, oracle12c, pljson

I'm having an issue with [PL/JSON](https://github.com/pljson/pljson) chopping off string values at exactly 5000 characters.

Example data: `{"n1":"v1","n2":"v2","n3":"10017325060844,10017325060845,... this goes on for a total of 32,429 characters  ...10017325060846,10017325060847"}`

After I convert the JSON string to an object I run this...

`dbms_output.put_line(json_obj.get('n3').get_string);`

And it only outputs the first 5000 characters.  So I did some digging, [see line 26 of this code](https://github.com/pljson/pljson/blob/master/src/pljson_value.type.impl.sql).  And right below it at line 31 the `extended_str` is being set and contains all 32,429 chars.  So now let's move on to the `get_string()` member function.  There are two of them.  I verified that it's the first one that is being called, the one with the `max_byte_size` and `max_char_size` parameters.  Both of those parameters are null.  So why is my text being chopped off at 5000 characters?  I need this to work for data strings of `varchar2(32767)` and `clobs`.  Thanks!

Version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

**UPDATE:** I found that the chopping of the text is coming from [line 35](https://github.com/pljson/pljson/blob/master/src/pljson_value.type.impl.sql): `dbms_lob.read(str, amount, 1, self.str);`.  I ignored this code before because I saw the comment and knew my string wasn't null.  So why is this read needed?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As maintainer of the pljson project I have answered your question on github (https://github.com/pljson/pljson/issues/154). For any further question feel free to ask on the same issue thread on github.